# MySQL Result consisted in more than one row

Tags: mysql

Alright, i have this piece of code which help me get details about post like text status, user name, date, date edited an so on, but the problem is i can get only one row from this function, how is possible to fetch multiple rows?

```
begin
    declare ipost text;

    select concat('{"response":1,"posts":[',
            '{',
            '"status":"',   data_comment.comment,'",',
            '"date":"',     data_datetime.time,'",',
            '"edited":"',   data_datetime.edited,'",',
            '"user":"',     concat(data_user_data.name,' ',data_user_data.lastname),'",',
            '"photo":', '{"', group_concat(data_photo.name separator '","'),'"}'
            '}'
    ,']}') 
    into ipost
    from data_post
        inner join data_user_data on data_user_data.id = data_post.id_user
        inner join data_datetime on data_datetime.id = data_post.id_date
        inner join data_comment on data_comment.id = data_post.id_comment
        inner join data_photo
        inner join fk_post__photo on fk_post__photo.id_post = data_post.id 
            and fk_post__photo.id_photo = data_photo.id
    group by data_post.id
    desc
    limit 4;


    if(ipost is null) then
        return '{"response":0}';
    else
        return ipost;
    end if;

end
```

**Edit:**

`replace`

```
inner join data_photo
inner join fk_post__photo on fk_post__photo.id_post = data_post.id 
    and fk_post__photo.id_photo = data_photo.id
```

`with`

```
inner join fk_post__photo on fk_post__photo.id_post = data_post.id 
inner join data_photo on data_photo.id = fk_post__photo.id_photo
```

Comment: here `inner join data_photo` is an on condition missing

Comment: And now you get the correct result?

Comment: No, i only add on condition to `data_photo`, maybe because we don't want to join the entire table

Comment: Then show sample data. Then it will be much more easier to help you.

Comment: `{"response":1,"posts":[{"status":"second brown comment jump ower first lazy dog","date":"2015-01-31 12:58:26","edited":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","user":"Johni Devo","photo":{"qwe.jpg","zxc.jpg"}}]}` is not tested (decoded) yes to see if i miss some coma or apostrophe

Comment: We need the database entries and the expected result. Not only the result you get.

Comment: I wanted to use group_concat function to wrap all the post result, but not working, i get error: invalid use of group function

Comment: ok i have made the 
`TABLE data_post (
 id INT(11) 
 id_comment
 id_photo
 id_date
 id_user
 INDEX Index 1 (id)` and i join all the other tables who have the data stored i only use this table like a fk table

Comment: the other table have only 2 column like `id` and `name` of the photo or `id` and `status` or `datetime` `editedtime`

Comment: i want to get the posts array `{"response":1,"posts":[{},{},{},{}]}` or to be able to get 4 different rows